# Linux, pthreads -- send stop condition

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix

I'm writing an application using phtreads and C under Linux. The main function starts a bunch of threads (up to 20). Then, under some criterion I need to stop all threads at once. Each thread is running under some conditional loop, like:

```
while (state) {....}
```

So I need to change state to false for each thread (I think at the moment it would be enough to have one state for each thread, but maybe in the future I'll have to stop each thread separately)

So, what's the best way to do it? I could use some *state* as a global variable and use mutex for it. Each time I will have to lock, read, unlock it to read it's value. And I think it's kinda of time consuming procedure. Do you have any other ideas how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# man pthread_cancel

allows you to send cancellation request to the thread.

# man pthread_cleanup_push

allows you to set cancellation routine.

Comment: Thank you. These routines look quite complex, but I guess there are no other ways to cancel running thread. BTW, is actually safe? I mean, if I call pthread_cancel() with pthread_setcanceltype as deferred, isn't it like 'putting somebody to sleep, using hammer'?

Comment: Yeah.. otherwise pthread_join will help you to wait for thread until it executes its routine.

Comment: Actually, I'm using pthread_join() already. But, as I said, I'm using some infinite loop within each thread (thread does dome communication with the serial port), and it will not *terminate* by itself. But, as far as I read from the man page, pthread_cancell() stops terminations of the thread as far as it reaches any of so-called *cancellation functions*. I'm using read() and write() in the beginning of my thread infinite loop and read() and write() are in the list of cancellation functions (man pthreads). So I do hope, that when I do pthread_cancell() my thread will be canceled as I expect

Comment: I am not sure. Sorry, but before you are going into infinite loop of read and write, you just set cancellation routine for a thread. And when you are canceling any thread from main, routine (cancellation routine) should have to clean up all shared tasks. (like lock, variables, etc..) and then thread was canceled.

Comment: read and write should not be in cancellation function. Cancellation function only executes when thread got cancel request.

Comment: Accoring to man pthread_cancel() : _Deferred cancelability means that cancellation will be delayed until the thread next calls a function that is a cancellation point. A list of functions that are or may be cancellation points is provided in pthreads(7)._  So, maybe I just did not express myself correctly: read() and write() will be *cancellation points*